# What does this line of code mean?

Tags: c

I am wondering what this line of code mean?

```
b = (gen_rand_uniform()>0.5)?1:0;
```

The `gren_rand_uniform()` is a function to generate random 0 and 1 numbers. However I don't get the meaning for `>0.5` and `1:0`.

I know this is supposed to be a basic question, please bear with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's shorthand.  In the example you gave, it is equivalent to:

```
if (gen_rand_uniform() > 0.5) {
    b = 1;
} else {
    b = 0;
}
```

Since `gen_rand_uniform()` probably generates uniformly distributed random numbers between `1` and `0`, there's a 50% chance of the value being higher than 0.5.  Which means there's a 50% chance of getting a `1` or a `0`

Comment: Its not shorthand, and its not exactly equivalent - it is in fact a separate construct.
This can most easily be seen when using nested ternary expressions, and seing in what order they are evaluated, left to right or vice versa. Of course, some might say that behaving in any other way than that of an 'equivalent' if/else contstruct must be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your input; I've somewhat qualified my answer.

Comment: That ternary operator is redundant; the effect of that statement is equivalent to `b = (gen_rand_uniform()>0.5);`

Answer (score 12):

I don't think `get_rand_uniform()` does what you think it does. It probably looks like this:

```
float get_rand_uniform(void);
```

Or maybe `double`. The point is, it returns a random *decimal* number *between* 0 and 1. So this:

```
get_rand_uniform() > 0.5
```

Is a check to see if that number is closer to 1 or 0. And this:

```
x ? y : z
```

Is the ternary conditional operator, which serves the same function as this:

```
if(x) { y } else { z }
```

Except that the ternary operator is an *expression*. So all of this:

```
get_rand_uniform() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0
```

Is basically rounding the random floating point number to 1 or 0, and this:

```
b = get_rand_uniform() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0;
```

Assigns that randomly picked 1 or 0 to `b`. I believe the parenthesis are unnecessary here, but if you like them, go for it.

Answer (score 3):

it's a way to get a random value which is either 1 or zero, each 50% of the time. The "?" and ":" are the [conditional operarator](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4eb.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's rounding. The b variable will either be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

It encodes a flip of the coin. (A perfectly balanced coin that is.)

Answer (score 0):

[Conditional assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_operator):

```
variable = condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false;
```

which is equal to:

```
if (condition) {
    variable = value_if_true;
} else {
    variable = value_if_false;
}
```

The code you give us is just random bool. It will return either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing here is a `ternary expression`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation
This is (as others here has pointed out) a conditional construct, but one that is specific to expressions, meaning that a value is returned.

This construct exist in most languages (but not in eg. VB.Net) and has the form of

```
condition ? valueiftrue: valueiffalse
```

An example of this in action is:

```
var foo = true;
var bar = foo ? 'foo is true' : 'foo is false';
// bar = 'foo is true'
```

Also note that the condition can be any expression (like in your case `gen_rand_uniform() > 0.5`) and can infact contain a nested ternary expression, all it has to do is evaluate as a non-false value.