# What in the world does this statement mean?

Tags: c, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What does this line of code mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567959/what-does-this-line-of-code-mean)

I was reading an article on [Opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection), and came across this:

```
for( i = 0; i < (faces ? faces->total : 0); i++ ) 
{
    CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces, i);
}
```

What in the world is this line supposed to mean:

`i < (faces ? faces->total : 0)`

Comment: if `faces` is `NULL`, don't enter loop, `else` iterate up to `faces->total`. It uses an implicit `if (something)` statement... If `faces` is anything but `NULL`, and that includes values >0 and <0, then it'll iterate up to `faces->total`.

Comment: It won't iterate up to `faces->total` if `faces` is changed to a null-pointer mid-loop. The part gets evaluated every iteration, so the loop could terminate early.

Comment: `?:` is the **conditional operator** which is a **kind of** ternary operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

The `(faces ? faces->total : 0)` tests `faces`. If it's true, then `faces->total` is returned and compared with `i`. Otherwise, if it evaluates to false, `i` is compared to `0`.

Comment: I meant how does it terminate the loop?

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Per Femaref's comment, my code below (original response) is *not* equivalent.  `faces` is likely modified by calling `cvGetSeqElem`, which in turn means that `faces->total` is probably modified as well.  So, the condition may change in each iteration and, if `faces` is null (`0`), the loop exits.

Still, it's confusing (got me!).  You could just as easily check for `faces` being null and exit the loop.  The loop counter potentially changes in each iteration, is dependent upon the `cvGetSeqElem` function mutating it, and just bleh.

---

It is a shorthand if statement called the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).  It is much the same as:

```
int count = 0;
if( faces )
  count = faces->total;

for( i = 0; i < count; i++ ) { 
    CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces, i);
}
```

So, if `faces` is null, `count` is `0` and the loop body never executes because the first test fails.  Of course, you could just check first if that is null and avoid the whole thing together. That code is ugly IMO.

```
if( faces ) {
    // do loop
}
```

Also, if `faces->total` is > 1 then you are just wasting cycles as only the last value returned by `cvGetSeqElem` will persist.  Of course, that function could have other side effects that are being relied upon, which would make the code even more convoluted than it already is.

Comment: Your code isn't equivalent to the code posted in the question. You'd query the value of `faces->total` once, but the sample points to `faces` being modified in the called method. Otherwise the code trick wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @Femaref: Good point, missed that.

Comment: It's only not equivalent if `cvGetSeqElem()` modifies `faces->total`. Given the fact that the other parameter to the function is `i`, I sure hope it doesn't... that would be a horrendous side effect.

Comment: @Ed It's actually unlikely that *any* of the values will persist, as the result is stored to a variable that only exists in the scope of the for loop. FWIW, I like your test of faces first, though.

Comment: @Quinn: I assumed that the rest of the code in the loop body was omitted.

Comment: @Quinn: I bet it does though.  The function must take a `SomeStruct**` and modify `faces` internally, otherwise it couldn't set it to `0`.  It is just ugly IMO...

Comment: @Ed S. yes, it is ugly, but probably done for optimization.

Comment: @Femaref: I sure hope so.  I'm curious as to what context this code is used in now.

Comment: Face detection (opencv is a library for intensive mathematical work). the link in the question points to the article.

Answer (score 2):

it is equivalent to

```
int output;

if(faces == 0)
  output = 0;
else
  output = faces->total;
```

(Note: this is just an explanation for the part in the for loop, not a replacement)

This is a trick in C. `faces` is in fact a pointer to a struct (visible by the `->` dereferencing). There is no Boolean type in C, 0 means false, every other value is true. In this case, the pointer is implicitly cast to int and than interpreted as Boolean in the [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a).

The loop is terminated once the pointer to the struct is `NULL`. `faces` is changed in the `cvGetSeqElem`.

Comment: The code sample wasn't meant to be a 1:1 replacement for the code, just an explanation. I'll point that out accordingly. If you meant the original code, the second part in the `for` loop gets evaluated on every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

It's iterating up to a value that is a member in a structure.

If the structure pointer is NULL, then it iterates zero times.

It's a safety feature to prevent dereferencing a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Vala.2C_Objective-C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript.2C_ActionScript): "if faces is true, then faces->total, otherwise zero".